# Calendar picker view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I am trying to get a calendar picker view for the user. So that the user can choose what calendar to show in the app and what not.
Does anyone know if there is any help with this in the EventKit framework or similar?
I would be very grateful for any help or point in direction!

like this one in apples calendar app:
[image]

thanx!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such default picker in the APIs, but you can recreate it, by using a grouped `UITableView`, you will have to create your own `UIImageView's` and on/off logic and then add your subviews to the `UITableViewCell` `contentView` property.